# Conexao via Bluetooth - Raspberry Pi 3 B + com dispositivos IoS

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth

**Qual o procedimento para habilitar o Bluetooth do Raspberry Pi 3 B+ para enviar e receber dados por bluetooth com IoS?**

Desenvolvi uma aplicação, onde através do bluetooth (Bluez, Pybluez e bluetoothctl) o raspberry recebe as informações de rede e se configura. Para dispositivos Android isto funcionou perfeitamente. Porém ao testar com dispositivos Apple (IoS) o bluetooth mesmo ligado, não chega a ser nem detectado. Alguém saberia me apontar qual o procedimento para habilitar o raspberry pi 3 B + para se comunicar com IoS?

**O Bluetooth é iniciado, através de shell script, da seguinte na maneira:**

```
bt-adapter --set Powered 1
bt-adapter --set DiscoverableTimeout 0
bt-adapter --set Discoverable 1
bt-adapter --set PairableTimeout 0
bt-adapter --set Pairable 1
```

**O script em python, responsável por lidar com a conexão é o seguinte:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM  )
    server_sock.bind(('', bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
    server_sock.listen(1)
    port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]
    bluetooth.advertise_service( server_sock, 'Rasp WiFi Configurator', 
                service_id = uuid, service_classes = [uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS], 
                profiles = [bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE])
    print('[INFO] Aguardando conexao bluetooth')
    client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
    print('[INFO] Conexao aceita de {}'.format(client_info))
    client_sock.send(json.dumps(net_info))
    bl_man = threading.Thread(target = bluetooth_manager, args = (server_sock, client_sock,))
    bl_man.start()
```